# Login/Logout issue with Play Framework?

Tags: java, playframework, securesocial

After user Logout, if user click on browser back button then user get Login page without enter his credentials. Please suggest me how to overcome this problem. I am using Securesocial module.
I am trying in so many ways:

1. Set headres on response.
2. Injecting meta tags to web pages.
3. Using custom javascript

I had set some headers on response object in logout action at server side https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/SgcVCXxZb7g

But the issue is not solved.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't know `securesocial` but you can redirect user to home page once logout is successful.

Comment: redirect("/");  its working fine but when user get Logout without performing  any operation after his login.If he perform any actions after login it's not working.